# A Novel that had dragon riding as a normal thing and the main character stole a runt to raise as his own

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, dragons

I read this book when I was very young and I wanted to find it again. 
Things I remember:

- Male and female humans as main roles
- Dragons are normal part of the world
- Riding dragons without proper saddles or doing it in a certain way can lead to major injuries or death
- Towards the end the whelpling grows up and has its own hatchlings and the two main characters end up taking care of them after the original dragon dies and they have to hide in its belly to survive freezing cold weather. Afterwards they had special eye power things? Like they saw in prism colors or something.

Comment: I guess this has already been answered but wow, everything but the last bit could apply to Anne McCaffrey's "The White Dragon", one of the Pern novels :)

Comment: @JasonK: First thing I thought of when I saw the title of the question.  But....Jaxom didn't steal his runt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably one of the books from the [Pit Dragon trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_Dragon_Trilogy) by Jane Yolen, specifically the second one, *[Heart's Blood](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/270641.Heart_s_Blood)*.

[image: Heart's Blood - Book Cover]

> Golden, Jakkin, and Akki flee to the mountains, but Golden is badly injured. Pursued by the Wardens, they are forced to leave Golden behind in a cave which they had sheltered in during Dark After, using Heart's Blood's body as a door and heater. Jakkin manumits the traitorous Erikkin, and Heart's Blood dies from a stinger shot in the neck, her body saving Jakkin and Akki. **The only shelter they have during Dark After, is Heart's Blood's body, so they crawl into her birth sac**. In the morning, Jakkin and Akki are reborn out of the dragon blood, and became the first real human Austarians, linked to each other and Heart's Blood's five hatchlings.

Jakkin and Akki are male and female. Dragons are common on Austar IV. Jakkin and Akki gain special powers by nesting in the birth sac, but it's the ability to communicate with each other as dragons do. And, from the [Google Books excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=AjT4GoHKgvkC&pg=PT296&lpg=PT296&dq=pit%20dragon%20trilogy%20saddles&source=bl&ots=Cwtn7gwlPa&sig=AkNl3vbmIS4P1-jCfbn-k1GSOLA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCqrSSs4_VAhVIbT4KHUnaDLYQ6AEIQzAE#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Jakkin added, "They can't be ridden. With a weight on Heart's Blood's back she couldn't even raise her wings. And if you sat there without a saddle of some sort, your legs and groin would be slashed terribly by her scales. The scales move when she moves, and they slice at a touch."